# HIBERNATE : Don't want to save milliseconds

Tags: java, hibernate

I got a little problem and I didn't find a suitable solution on the net because my question is a bit tricky for search engine.

There's a lot of topics about hibernate saving milliseconds. But my problem is something else.

In fact, I got a database, which save my date like this :

```
2014-03-20 10:58:09
```

I used **Hibernate** to get back my date, and display it on a web page. But Hibernate retrieve more than that : it also retrieve a 0 milliseconds, like this :

```
2014-03-20 10:58:09.0
```

Many people seems to have problem with this, but in my case, I **DON'T WANT** this information, I want Hibernate to retrieve the date **without this .0** !

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT AND SOLUTION :**

Ok so I made it by using a little hack.

In my specific object using by Hibernate, I had this method :

```
public Date getModificationDate() {
      return modificationDate;
   }
```

I just simply create an other method :

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat FMT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

public String getModificationDateLabel() {
        if (modificationDate != null) {
            return FMT.format(modificationDate);
        }
        return null;
}
```

So, when I display in my webpage (I use Velocity Template), I just run through my list of object an display the label :

```
#foreach( $object in $objects)
$!{object.modificationDateLabel}
#end
```

The SimpleDateFormat allow me to remove the .0, and by creating a new method, I don't disturb the behavior of getting a Date with Hibernate.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Which hibernate version are you using?

Comment: Use a format pattern for `SimpleDateFormat` that does not include milliseconds.

Comment: How are you displaying it? You need to _format_ your date before displaying it, just calling `toString` is not going to get you anywhere.

Comment: I display in a web page (using Velocity) but when I retrieve my data, it's in a list of specific object. I can't parse it with a SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem with the date returned as "2014-03-20 10:58:09.0" is equal to "2014-03-20 10:58:09". Can you provide specific scenario where this can result in issue?

Or use SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") then parse your date in this format before using the date.

Comment: Well, the thing is that I need to display the date on a web page. I just retrieve all my data in a list of specific object. When I'm displaying it, I see a date in this format "2014-03-20 10:58:09.0", but I don't want to see the .0.

Comment: In some scenarios managing many Dates from many classes, using SimpleDateFormat would be a real pain, not to mention if one day you want to change your solution.