# MVC + Hibernate + Spring, date sending error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, date

I have a problem with edition.

In my MySQL database there is a date column. When I get it through DAO i have something like `"2015-01-20 19:00:00.0"`. My update method works with the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"`. There is no problem with add method, because when I click on the date input in my view - jquery formats it automatically (*datetimepicker*). And there is no problem when I'm changing the date in edit method (same script). The problem is when i get the data from database to my view and I just need to change name or something other than date. But the problem is - if i'm not clicking on the input form the pattern stays `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.f"` and it's sent like this. And I get the http 400 error (syntax).

I'm using `java.util.Date` with dao for this variable. If I use `SimpleDateFormat` I get deserialised error. If I use joda i get syntax error while sending `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"` through my view.

Is there any chance my database can store date in `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"` pattern?

Comment: Can you share the code where you receive that date?

Comment: @Column(name = "StartDate")
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
private Date startDate;

and later standard getter and setter

Comment: Sorry! My bad! I mean the servlet code, JSF, REST, etc.

Comment: Answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537226/hibernate-dont-want-to-save-milliseconds